# Singleton design pattern. Should its instance be public or private?

Tags: java, singleton, modifier

Is it necessary for instance of singleton design pattern to be private or public to be considered a singleton design pattern .
for example

class Singleton
{
public static Singleton obj;

is the access modifier neccessary. What difference does it make.

Comment: It's a singleton that is unsafe (anyone can do `Singleton.obj = null;`) and probably not thread-safe (that would need double checked locking and `obj` to be `volatile` or preferably use the singleton holder approach(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) but `public static final instance = new Singleton();` is already a perfectly (thread-)safe singleton. The GOF pattern would want you to use getters rather than public fields but that's a different debate

Answer (score 0):

In my view it's necessary for the instance of a singleton design pattern to be private, because somebody may Singleton.obj when it's not be initialized, it is dangerous